# Capture an error when making a post in restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

When I call a web service, it catch Error 422, but it does not allow me to retrieve the response.

The options

```
options = new RestClientOptions
            {
                ThrowOnAnyError = true,
                MaxTimeout = -1,
            };
```

```
        public async Task<Procesar> SendProcessAsync(Procesar procesar)
        {
            try
            {

                var client = new RestClient(options);
                var request = new RestRequest($"{url}request/{procesar.request_token}/process", Method.Post);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.access_token}");
                var param = new { procesar.status_node, procesar.worknote };
                request.AddBody(param);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(request);
                if (response.IsSuccessful)
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Procesar>(response.Content);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Response_Exception(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response_Error>(response.Content));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                logger.Error(exception);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The response is:

```
{
    "error_code": 4000,
    "error_msg": "El formulario enviado no es válido",
    "extra_data": {
        "message": "->: Nodo destino incorrecto.:false;    ->status_node: Este valor no es válido.:6454aeee4090275eda0ab423;    ",
        "errors": [
            {
                "field": "",
                "message": "Nodo destino incorrecto.",
                "parameters": "false"
            },
            {
                "field": "status_node",
                "message": "Este valor no es válido.",
                "parameters": "6454aeee4090275eda0ab423"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can someone help me tell me how I can capture the message that I receive?

I need to get what comes in the response

Comment: "but it does not allow me to retrieve the response."How does it fail? What do you get instead? How your options for the RestClient look?

Comment: This not fail, but I need retrieve the response body. This directly catch error 422 .

Comment: You have set ThrowOnAnyError in the options to true. Your response.IsSuccessful code only makes sense if you don't do that. Currently PostAsync will throw an exception because of that and your exception handler will only log the exception.

Comment: Seems like PostAsync always throws exceptions ignoring the ThrowOnAnyError setting. You might try switching to ExecutePostAsync instead and still leave ThrowOnAnyError as false.

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution worked great for me.